# General Failure Sending SMS

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, smsmanager

I have an app that send sms once the user do a certain action.

**PRE-Conditions:**

- Text is limited to 100 characters
- PhoneNumber doesn't have the country code and exists

In order to detect if the SMS have a successfully sent, I have a broadcastReceiver with cases and an external log to check if all is working:

- SENT
- RADIO OFF
- GENERAL FAILURE
- ETC..

Seems that the code works, but I can't understand why I have these random general failures. In some countries like Mexico, I have a lot of General failures and there is nothing in commun instead of country and operator. 80% of cases are general failures. MEXICO/TELCEL.

I said random, because inclusive with the same user, I got "SENT" and "General failure". Is crazy.

I don't post the code because is very simple and generic, and I think that is more a theoretical question.

What means a generic failure? It depends on the operator/country/device/network? I have to do something different depending of these factors?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ? I can't figure it out too.